# NAS suitable for this situation?

Tags: linux, postgresql, network-attached-storage

I work from home and am considering getting a NAS. Would using a NAS be suitable for my situation:

- I alternate working from a desktop and laptop, both of which run Linux
- I use PostgreSQL a lot along with doing python development. The idea would be to store the databases on the NAS along with all my program code.
- I would run a copy of PostgreSQL on both the desktop and laptop which would connect to the NAS for the databases. That way when im working on either machine I will have access to my databases and program code.

Would this set work and would a NAS be the way to go?

Also, lets say I update the structure of a database from my desktop. Then at a later time I startup postgresql on the laptop and connect to the database (stored on the NAS) that was updated from the desktop.

Will that cause issues or will postgresql automatically pick up the changes. In other words, when updating the structure of the database from the desktop, is any critical information stored locally on the desktop that pertains to the database,...or is it all in the db itself which will be on the NAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly right place to ask this question, but I'll throw in my $.02 anyway.

Get something, that runs linux. Install Postgres on it. Connect to it via TCP. Having the same database files accessed by two different computers would either not work, or lead to data corruption and cluster headaches. (besides being slow)

Use git for code. It's defacto standard these days and it will help you work with the code even when you walk away from home with your laptop.